# Query to Fetch Matching Records between 2 tables and not matching Null records from Second Tabl2

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union, oracle12c

I've 2 tables as below. I need to fetch the matching names between the 2 tables and also the unmatching NULL Records in the 2second table. The Column Number (key Vlaues) should be in Join . I used the below query. But is there any way to get rid of Union, or is there any other better way of writing the query than below?

```
  FirstTable
    Number|Name
      1   |Oracle
      2   |SAP
      3   |IQ
      4   |HANA
      5   |Oracle

    Second Table
    Number|Name
      1   |Oracle
      2   |
      3   |Sybase
      4   |HANA
      5   |
    Query:
    -------
    select a.name from FirstTable a, Secondtable b 
    where a.number=b.number
    and a.name=b.name
    and b.name is not null

    union

    select a.name from FirstTable a, Secondtable b 
    where a.number=b.number
    and b.name is  null

    Required Output 

    Name
    Oracle
    SAP
    HANA
```

Comment: SAP is not matched in both tables so it will not come to the output

Comment: Corrected the Query now, In the first Query, both number and name is joined and in the second query only number is joined.

Comment: but in that case iq and sybase also come into output

Comment: You should show what results you want.  I don't think the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me for this request is more convenient  something like

```
select distinct a.name from FirstTable a,SecondTable b
where a.number=b.number and a.name=nvl(b.name,a.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

use  join and union all and never use coma separated join

```
  select coalesce(a.name,b.name) as name from 
  Secondtable b  join FirstTable a
  a.name=b.name or a.number=b.number 
  union all
  select name from Secondtable where name is null
```